Future response in a RestController returns the future data instead of the actual response
Using Spring Boot 3.1.3
My Application class:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}

My rest controller:
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @GetMapping
  public Future<String> show() {
    return this.myService.doInAsync();
  }
}

The async service:
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Async
  public Future<String> doInAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Jordi");
  }
}

The response of the operation is:
{
  "cancelled": false,
  "done": true
}

When it should be "Jordi".
However if I remove the @Async annotation it works as expected.
Am I doing something wrong?

You shouldn't use @Async on a controller method, it interferes with the async servlet api support. So remove @Async. So yes you are doing something wrong using @Async in the wrong place.

@M.Deinum that's not the reason. Using async out of the controller also does not work. I have updated the example to avoid confusion

The problem is the async in async. You have 3 threads here. First the normal request handling thread, second the thread started by the async support in Spring for the async response, third the thread started by @Async. Due to the 3rd thread, thread 2 returns directly without any result and as it didn't have time to properly start it will be not handled by the proper async support in Spring but marshalled by Jackson (hence you see the result as you see). So yes the problem is still the @Async in an async servlet API.

For some reason, when changing the response type of MyService from Future to CompletableFuture it works correctly.
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<String> doInAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Jordi");
  }
}

